# How do I remove Bower from a ASP.NET Core Web application?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, bower

**Problem**

I created an ASP.NET Core Web App on Ubuntu and it runs fine.

[image: project list]

However, it seems to have included bower by default. I want my web project to handle serving the site, but to have any of the Javascript/SASS/CSS etc generation to be handled in isolation by Webpack in conjunction with a few other things.

[image: bundle config][image]

**Question**

How do I cleanly remove bower from my project?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Delete `bower_modules` (or `wwwroot\lib`) folder, depending on which version of tooling you are using
2. Delete `bower.json`

Comment: Isn't some part of the project explicitly running bower, though? What you've mentioned seems reasonable, but I imagined somewhere there would be a call to bower. Is this not the case?

Comment: No. Every time you edit the bower file, the VS2017/VS Code will run `bower install` command line. But nothing is stored in the project files. Same for `packages.json` (Node/NPM)

Comment: This might be for another question/me reading further articles, but I'll try in this comment anyway. Even if I take away the Bower stuff, it seems .NET Core MVC tries to automate somethings (as seen in bundleconfig.json). How can I take this away completely so the project when run literally does nothing but serve the site? Edit: Meant to say thanks so much for your help, it's greatly appreciated.

Comment: `bundleconfig.json` is unrelated to bower, but will bundle js files to one source file. It's likely associated with the "Task Runner Explorer" (where also gulp and grunt task run if you have the configured) and will usually trigger on build and also in csproj you can add your own commands to execute on publishing/building, for example  `<Target Name="PrepublishScript" BeforeTargets="PrepareForPublish">`